# access custom xml-element from listPopWindow

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow, baseadapter

I have a listPopupWindow, when I click on a list item in the listPopupWindow I want to take the clicked value and set it into my class that extends EditText (called Helper). I however fail to do this.

I populate the list via a BaseAdapter. I have added a setClickListner like this in the 
Here is the code for the Adapter.

...myAdapter extends BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final CustomView cw = new CustomView(context, (String)getItem(position)); //another custom element..


     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
     final EditText editText = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.helper); 


    cw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            editText.setText(cw.getName()); //here is the problem

        }
    });

    return cw;
}
```

I'm trying to access the following xml-element in the activity_main.xml

```
   <com.example.test.Helper
    android:id="@+id/helper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is the EditText class

```
public class Helper extends EditText{
 //stuff
 //here is where a I want the result to end up in...
}
```

And here is how is instantiated

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 }
```

}

I can't access the EditText-element, every approach I've tried has given med 
a Null pointer exception. Do I need to inflate the activity_main to access its elements? 
How do I reach the XML-element called helper?